# How do I combine two lists to a List<KeyValuePair<>>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

There are two lists:

```
List<string> files;
List<Filter> filters;
```

I want the result to be like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>> fileFilterMap;
```

I tried several stuff (lambda expressions, linq) but failed.
I really do not want the

`for(int i = 0; i< files.count; i++)`

method.

Comment: How do you want to map them? Index 0 with index 0?

Comment: Why no `for` loop? Chances are that it'll be more readable *and* more efficient than the alternatives.

Comment: People seem to start liking for loops again because they're not aware of all LINQ features. If you look at the answers, most of them look really cryptic, however it's a _short_ one-liner with Enumerable.Zip()

Comment: @noah1989 WoW! Fantastic! Liked this feature )) Never knew about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>> fileFilterMap =
  Enumerable.Range(0, files.Count)
  .Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, Filter>(files[i], filters[i]))
  .ToList();
```

Or:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>> fileFilterMap =
  Enumerable.Zip(
    files,
    filters,
    (file, filter) => new KeyValuePair<string, Filter>(file, filter)
  )
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This is what Enumerable.Zip does, but with a few flaws: For example, what happens when files.Count > filters.Count?

Comment: @noah1989: Right, didn't think of that. I'll add it.

Comment: Enumerable.Zip if for .Net 4. Anything for 3.5 or less?

Comment: @odyodyodys: Yes, use the first option.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

```
var fileFilterMap = Enumerable.Zip(files, filters, (file, filter) => new KeyValuePair(file, filter));
```

Comment: favorite solution so far. Neat and easy! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean that the two lists are in synch with each other to begin with, then

```
var fileFilterMap = files.Select((s, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s, filters[i])).ToList();
```

Will work.

That said, what's so wrong with `for(int i; i != files.Count; ++i)`. I'd consider that to be superior (slightly quicker, much clearer).

Answer (score 1):

Thinking that your `Filter` class contains the property Prop by which it is conditioned here is the excerpt.

```
    public class Filter {
        public String Prop { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var strings = new List<String>();
        var filters = new List<Filter>();

        var result = strings.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, Filter>(x,filters.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Prop == x)))
            .ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, although it's not very pretty.. (As it does a IndexOf look-up for each item in files. And it requires each entry in files to be *unique*.)

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();

List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>> fileFilterMap =
     files.ToDictionary(
          file => file, // key selector
          file => filters[files.IndexOf(file)] // item selector
     ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>> fileFilterMap = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Filter>>();
files.All(a => { fileFilterMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Filter>(a, filters[files.IndexOf(a)])); return true; });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileFilterMap = files.Zip(filters, (file, filter) => new KeyValuePair<string,Filter>(file, filter)).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this answer much better.  precise and concise... thanks for bringing this up...